# How to read function names from file and prefix file with said function names in Bash effectively?

Tags: string, bash, unix, terminal

I have a bunch of files which I concatenate into one large file. The single large file then looks like this:

```
function foo() {
  // ... implementation
}

function bar() {
  // ... implementation
}

function baz() {
  // ... implementation
}

function foo_bar() {
  // ... implementation
}

...
```

A bunch of functions. I want to create a new file with all this content, PLUS prefixing it with this:

```
module.exports = {
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  foo_bar,
  ...
}
```

Basically exporting every function. What is the most simple, cleanest way I can do this in bash?

As far as I got is this haha, it is really confusing to try and come up with a solution:

```
A := out/a.js
B := out/b.js

all: $(A) $(B)

$(A):
  @find src -name '*.js' -exec cat {} + > $@

$(B):
  @cat out/a.js | grep -oP '(?function )[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(? \{)'

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve this of problem in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the list of functions declared before and after sourcing the file. Compute the difference. You can get the list of currently declared functions with `declare -F`.

```
A() { :; }
pre=$(declare -F | sed 's/^declare -f //')

function foo() {
  // ... implementation
}

function bar() {
  // ... implementation
}

function baz() {
  // ... implementation
}

function foo_bar() {
  // ... implementation
}

post=$(declare -F | sed 's/^declare -f //')

diff=$(comm -13 <(sort <<<"$pre") <(sort <<<"$post"))

echo "module.exports = {
    $(<<<"$diff" paste -sd, | sed 's/,/,\n\t/g')
}"
```

I think with `bash --norc` you should get a clean environment, so with `bash --norc -c 'source yourfile.txt; declare -F'` you could get away with computing the difference:

```
cat <<EOF >yourfile.txt
function foo() {
  // ... implementation
}

function bar() {
  // ... implementation
}

function baz() {
  // ... implementation
}

function foo_bar() {
  // ... implementation
}
EOF

diff=$(bash --norc -c 'source yourfile.txt; declare -F' | cut -d' ' -f3-)

echo "module.exports = {
    $(<<<"$diff" paste -sd, | sed 's/,/,\n\t/g')
}"
```

Both code snippets should output:

```
module.exports = {
    bar,
    baz,
    foo,
    foo_bar
}
```

Note: the `function name() {}` is a mix of ksh and posix form of function definition - the ksh uses `function name {}` while posix uses `name() {}`. Bash supports both forms and also the strange mix of both forms. To be portable, just use the posix version `name() {}`. More info maybe at [wiki-deb-bash-hackers.org obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Answer (score 1):

This simple `awk` script will do it

```
awk -F '( |\\()' 'BEGIN {print "module.exports = {"} /function/ {print "\t" $2 ","} END {print "}"}' largefile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `echo` and `sed`:

```
echo 'modules.exports = {'; sed -n 's/^function \([^(]*\)(.*/  \1,/p' input.txt; echo '}'
```

result:

```
modules.exports = {
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  foo_bar,
}
```